# How can I change all forms properties in C# Windows Application

Tags: c#

Example:

1- List all forms (opened and closed Forms) in the C# windows forms project

2 - Set properties like at:

```
* Size
* StartPosition
*ShowInTaskbar
```

3- Call this before the application start.

With this I want to set properties only once in the beginning for all forms and have the same standard. Thank you.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just set them in the properties window of the IDE?

Comment: @CharlesMay Picture a project with dozens (hundreds?) of forms with the same property values, then one property needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this during run-time with an extension method.

```
public static class FormExtensions
{
    public static Form SetFormProperties(this Form form)
    {
        form.Height = 100;
        form.Width = 100;
        form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.WindowsDefaultLocation;
        form.ShowInTaskbar = true;
        return form;
    }
}
```

And then call it when you create an instance of a form.

```
var newForm = new SomeForm().SetFormProperties();
```

Comment: Probably not ideal.  Some of those properties need to be set in a form's constructor to work properly or avoid side effects.

Comment: @LarsTech That's a good point I hadn't thought about.

Comment: i use this for change the WinForm BorderColor after the
    
`InitializeComponent();
    this.SetFormProberties();`